# Defining and calling function in puppet 2.6 and 2.7

Tags: puppet

I have a module `core` and a class `core::logrotate` defined in `core/manifests/logrotate.pp`.

```
class core::logrotate {
#...some stuff here
#
  define confd ($ensure = "present" , $log_name = "dummy" ) {
    if ( $ensure == present )
    {
        file {
          "/etc/logrotate.d/$log_name":
            ensure => present,
            source => filelookup("core/${log_name}.logrotate"),
        }
    } else {
        file {
          "/etc/logrotate.d/$log_name":
           ensure => absent,
        }
    }
  }  
}
```

calling this function inside of templates.pp as

`core::logrotate::confd { "mkill": log_name => mkill }`

This fails with the error

`Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type core::logrotate::confd`

If the puppet master version is 2.6.x then this fails, to make it work there used to be a import "*" in the init.pp of the module. Now removed this as moving to puppet 2.7.20.

The code pasted here works in 2.7 but fails in 2.6. Any idea why? how can I make it work for both 2.6 and 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the define outside of the class, see the style guide: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#classes

Also, I think that you might be using modules wrong, it would be much more logical to have a 'logrotate' module on its own.

So; in modulepath/logrotate/manifests/confd.pp you'd put this:

```
define logrotate::confd ($ensure = "present" , $log_name = "dummy" ) {
  if ( $ensure == present )
  {
    file {
      "/etc/logrotate.d/$log_name":
        ensure => present,
        source => filelookup("core/${log_name}.logrotate"),
    }
  } else {
    file {
      "/etc/logrotate.d/$log_name":
       ensure => absent,
    }
  }
}
```

That should make it work properly.

Greetings,
Ger